# RegEx - match delimiters unless within (nested) angle brackets

Tags: regex, delphi, split, delimiter

I'm trying to split the following (Delphi RTTI output) by the namespace delimiter `.`:

```
System.Generics.Collections.TEnumerator<Utils.TPair<System.string,System.string>>
```

The correct split should be `[System, Generics, Collections, TEnumerator<Utils.TPair<System.string,System.string>>]`.

First I tried a negative lookahead `\.(?!\<*[a-zA-Z0-9_.,]*\>)`, but that matched both the period in `Utils.TPair` and the leftmost `System.string`. I am a little surprised, I might add, that it (correctly) matched the period in `Collections.TEnumerator`. I guess this is a testament to my command of the regex language.

So I tried making it "greedier" by saying this: `\.(?!\<*[a-zA-Z0-9_.,<>]*\>)`, but then no match was found. (I know this isn't what regexers usually mean when they say "greedy", but I couldn't come up with a more suitable description.)

So I decided to go back to scratch. As far as I understand, I should be able to use negative lookarounds to solve my case. In particular: *any match following `<` can effectively be ignored*. So I decided [`(?<!\<[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\.`](http://regexr.com?3265j) should solve my problem. It doesn't. Which probably is due to the fact that (many) negative lookbehind implementations don't support variable length strings. (To be specific, PCRE - which is basically what Delphi uses, apparently support variable length alternates. Every alternate has to be fixed at execution, though.)

And thus I turn to you, the Community.

Can anyone please shed some light on this problem, which actually should be quite simple? Would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\.(?![^.]*[\w_.,]*>)
```

It basically means: Match all `.` that are not followed by a `.` that is before a `>` und thus inside a `<>`.
It is actually very limited to your example.

See on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/LuzaLtgX3f)

A negativ lookbehind can solve this task better:

```
(?<!<.{0,1000})\.
```

It means match any `.` that does not have a `<` before it.

I tried this in java and it works. Java does not allow to have unlimited lookbehinds, thats why I used a limit of 1000 `{0,1000}` instead of `*`. I don't know if PCRE supports it.

Comment: You are kidding me - that was _fast_! Works perfectly. Thanks morja! If I may ask: why are you using the negated character class? I'm reading it like this: Match all periods. But not if the period is followed by anything but a period (an unspecified number of times) then open bracket an unspecified number of times, then a character class an unspecified number of times and finally a closing bracket. What's wrong with my reading?

Comment: See my comment. I also updated the regex. Hope my explanation makes some sense and the regex fits your needs regardless of its limitation.

Comment: I added a second expression that should cover more cases.

Comment: Thanks morja, that makes sense. :) I checked the negative lookbehind as well, but got an exception regarding the non-fixed length.